# Execute RxJava observable as readOnly within Spring boot Transaction?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, rx-java

Within my spring boot app I made several database calls asynchronously like so:

```
public List<Results> doWork() {
        List<Observable<Results>> observables = Lists.newArrayList();

        observables.add(
          Observable.fromCallable(() -> dbQueryMethod(param1)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));

        observables.add(
          Observable.fromCallable(() -> dbQueryMethod(param2)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));

        return Observable.merge(observables)
                    .toList()
                    .toBlocking()
                    .single();
}

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Results> myServiceMethod() {
    doWork();
}
```

Basically the issue is that despite marking my service layer method as transaction & read only set to true, it's not actually passing the ThreadLocal state to the new threads spawned off by RxJava, causing the connections go to my master db instance and not the read replica.

We are currently using configured `ContextHandlers` and a `ContextAwareSchedulerHook` in `App.java`, but what do I need to do so that the new threads created by RxJava will inherit whatever ThreadLocal state is needed to manage them within the defined transaction?

Comment: You can add copy your thread local to another thread using a SchedulerHook, see http://blog.mabn.pl/2014/11/rxjava-logback-and-mdc-threadlocal.html (for RxJava 1)

Comment: @dwursteisen but is there anything that shows how specifically to do this for spring JDBC state?

Answer (score 0):

Mark your `dbQueryMethod` with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` and make sure you invoke it via Spring autowired proxy (not directly from the same class). Then `io` thread shall start new transaction, which will be read only.